# Can't load pickle with custom preprocessing classes

Tags: python, fastapi, pickle, joblib

I have two folders:

- notebooks (where I've trained the model)
- src/main.py

In main.py I'm trying to load the model using joblib but I get an error that the custom preprocessing classes can't be found. Even though, I've imported it.

```py
import logging
from logging import config
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, HTTPException, status

from domain.services import PredictionService
from usecase.item import ItemReadModel
from utils.preprocess import PriceImputer

import joblib

# config.fileConfig("logging.conf", disable_existing_loggers=False)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

app = FastAPI()

model = joblib.load("models/logistic_regression_model.joblib")
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'PriceImputer' on <module '__mp_main__' from '...'>
```

But as you may see, I've already imported it.

[EDIT]
I just needed to load the model under the `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    model = joblib.load("models/logistic_regression_model.joblib")
    prediction_service = PredictionService(model)
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Comment: WHERE do you get that error?  Which line?  And please show the whole traceback.

Comment: I get it when loading model

Comment: What does that mean?  Does that mean the `joblib.load` statement?

Comment: I've already fixed it. I just needed to load the model under `if __name__ == '__main__':` in the `main.py` file.